# How to check if the cart contains any bundled products?

Tags: magento-1.7, onepage-checkout

I'm needing the find out how to check if the cart has any bundles products in it. If so then the standard 'Proceed to Checkout' shows, if not then text is displayed.

This is what I've got to so far but this just doesn't display anything.

```
<?php $cartdata = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getData();?>
<?php $bundlesincart = $cartdata->addFieldToFilter('type_id','bundle');?>
    <?php if (!$bundlesincart):?>
        <p>No Package Selected</p>
    <?php else:?>
        <?php if ($this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout()):?>
            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Proceed to Checkout') ?>" class="button btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout<?php if ($this->isDisabled()):?> no-checkout<?php endif; ?>"<?php if ($this->isDisabled()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif; ?> onclick="window.location='<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>';"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Proceed to Checkout') ?></span></span></button>
        <?php endif?>
    <?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to loop through all the products in the cart items what you could do would be to get the quote id and load the items directly from the database, including the product type filter.

```
/** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Quote $quote */
$quoteId = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getId();
/** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Item_Collection $quoteItems */
$quoteItems = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection();
$quoteItems->addFieldToFilter('quote_id', $quoteId);
$quoteItems->addFieldToFilter('product_type', 'bundle');

if ($quoteItems->getSize() >= 1) {
    echo 'We have bundle products';
}
```

Comment: This answer also works great works with a slightly improved method. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
    if($item->getProduct()->getTypeID() == 'bundle'){
        //$item is bundle item
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you. Cannot upvote due to my rep unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $productType = $item->getProduct()->getTypeID();
}
```